# Tranisition css with transform causing shadow like element to be created at random position

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, bootstrap-4

I have simple `div` with class `.inbound` (set by `ngClass`), which I am flipping based on a CSS transform (rotateY) in SCSS.

```
<div class="row flow_control">
        <div>
          <label class="flow_switch">
            <input type="checkbox" (change)="changeFlowDir($event)">
            <span class="flow_slider"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row flow" [ngClass]="{'inbound':current?.flowDirection==='inbound'}">
        <div class="col-md-4 entity">
          Agent
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="flow_hub"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 entity">
          Edge
        </div>
      </div>
```

Corresponding SCSS

```
    .flow{
            position: relative;
            // margin: 3rem auto;
            // transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: transform 1s;
            .entity{
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
            .agent{
                float: left;
            }
            .edge{
                float: right;
            }
            .flow_hub{
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: 60px;
                width: 60px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background-color: #c2d0e5;
            }
            &.inbound{
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
            }
        }
```

The flip animation works but a pseudo-element is visible at random position on DOM while the animation is happening.

Comment: Can you post all the code?

Comment: I don't see a flip animation or a psuedo element style. Also, could you be more specific on the _simple "div"_ .... your code sample has many div's in it, which one are you talking about (give a class or id)

Comment: This happeningg only for rotateY transform.

Comment: Voted to close quesiton: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).